# Downloading Image from Azure Blob C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I am trying to download an image (.jpg) from an Azure storage blob using:

```
 public static async Task DownloadToTemp(string path, string fileName)
    {
        string storageAccount_connectionString = "CONNECTION STRING";

        CloudStorageAccount mycloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageAccount_connectionString);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = mycloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(CONTAINER);
        CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

        // provide the file download location below            
        Stream file = File.OpenWrite(path);    
          

        await cloudBlockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(file);

        file.Close();

        return;
    }
```

But when I try to open the image as a bit map `Bitmap image = new Bitmap(path)` I am getting the error `System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.'`. I am using the call `BlobHandler.DownloadToTemp(path, file).GetAwaiter()` to ensure the file has been downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem lies with not waiting fully for the image to be stored:
adding:

```
await BlobHandler.DownloadToTemp(path, file);
```

Ensures that the file is fully downloaded (This meant that the callerfunction had to be async).